# Monster Chase pygame

Tags: python, pygame

So here is my problem , I'm at the (very) beginning of making my Rogue like game and i'm stuck at making an enemy chase the player , it must be something  easy and obvious but my skills are pretty low ... So here is my Monster class

```
class monster():
  def __init__(self , mright, mleft, mup, mdown):
    self.mright = pygame.image.load(mright).convert_alpha()
    self.mleft = pygame.image.load(mleft).convert_alpha()
    self.mup = pygame.image.load(mup).convert_alpha()
    self.mdown = pygame.image.load(mdown).convert_alpha()

    self.sqrx = 7 
    self.sqry = 2
    self.x = 210
    self.y = 60
    self.direction = self.mdown

    char = character(right , left , up , down , Level)

def chase(self,direction):
    if self.sqrx > char.sqrx :
        self.sqrx -= 1
        self.x = self.sqrx * size_sprite 
    self.direction = self.mleft

    if self.sqrx < char.sqrx :
        self.sqrx += 1
        self.x = self.sqrx * size_sprite 
    self.direction = self.mright

    if self.sqry > char.sqry :
        self.sqry -= 1
        self.y = self.sqry * size_sprite
    self.direction = self.mup

    if self.sqry < char.sqry :
        self.sqry += 1
        self.y = self.sqry * size_sprite
    self.direction = self.mdown
```

And the Game Loop

```
while gameon:


    pygame.time.Clock().tick(30)

    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == QUIT:
            gameon = 0
            on = 0

        elif event.type == KEYDOWN:

            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                gameon = 0

            elif event.key == K_RIGHT:
                char.move('right')  
            elif event.key == K_LEFT:
                char.move('left')
            elif event.key == K_UP:
                char.move('up')
            elif event.key == K_DOWN:
                char.move('down')

    level.display(window)
    window.blit(monst.direction , (monst.x , monst.y))
    window.blit(char.direction , (char.x , char.y))
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: you have wrong indentions in code. In `chase` you always set `self.direction = self.mdown`

Comment: @furas The self.direction is only a sprite for character

Comment: but `chase(self,direction):` always set `self.direction = self.mdown` - it doesn't matter what `direction` you use. (BTW: "comment" is place for comments to all code, not only for answer/solution)

Comment: where do you use `chase()` ? i don't see it in code.

Comment: use `chase()` after events but before `level.display()` - see one of [template](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/blob/master/pygame/__template__/3__app_class__.py) - part "updates" in mainloop. You probably use local (or global) variables `char` in `chase()` - I would use `chase(char)` or set `moster = Moster(char)` and use `self.char` in all functions in `Moster()`

Comment: i dont use it anywhere because i dont know how to use i will use it obviously on the loop but dont know how and for the direction i use the self.direction = self.mdown as a default direction and i thought that after the if test he would change is direction and moving squares right away

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `chase()` in mainloop - see comment in code

```
while gameon:

    pygame.time.Clock().tick(30)

    # --- events ---

    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == QUIT:
            gameon = 0
            on = 0

        elif event.type == KEYDOWN:

            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                gameon = 0

            elif event.key == K_RIGHT:
                char.move('right')  
            elif event.key == K_LEFT:
                char.move('left')
            elif event.key == K_UP:
                char.move('up')
            elif event.key == K_DOWN:
                char.move('down')
        # - object events ---

        # char.handle_event(event)

    # --- updates ---

    # HERE put all functions which change elements
    #      (but don't depend on events) like:
    # - chasing player, 
    # - moving mosters, 
    # - detecting collisions, 
    # - animating other elements (ie. fire, water, etc.)

    # --- draws all elements ---

    level.display(window)
    window.blit(monst.direction , (monst.x , monst.y))
    window.blit(char.direction , (char.x , char.y))
    pygame.display.flip()
```

See some [templates of PyGame code](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/pygame/__template__)

---

In Moster I would use `char` (player instance) as argument in

```
def __init__(self , char, ...):
    self.char = char
```

to have access to its position all the time

or at least

```
def chase(self, direction, char):
```

to have access to player when you call `chase()`

---

**BTW:** instead of `gameon = 0` more readable is `gameon = False` (and `gameon = True`)

---

You could create `draw()` in `Moster()` and do

```
 monst.draw(window)
```

instead of

```
 window.blit(monst.direction , (monst.x , monst.y))
```

---

Use `CamelCase` names for classes (`class Monster():`) and `lower_case` names for variables (`moster = Moster()`). It makes code more readable. See [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: Tanks for your advice ! i will try to correct my errors and try your exemple .

Comment: So i have no more indentation issue and clearier code thanks to you but i cant figure out how to use the class i have just created , in the main loop i used  "For event in " to make my character move it was simple but i dont know how to use my chase() function in my loop any hint ?

Comment: In part `--- updates ---` use `monst.chase()`. But probably you will have to modify this function because I'm not sure if it does what you expect.

Comment: example code: [follow player](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/pygame/follow-player)

Comment: Thank you very much ! my monster is finally moving and following my player thanks to you .

Answer (score 0):

Like someone mentioned above - your indentation of setting the direction is causing it to call all 4 of the assignments every time `chase` is called. This essentially always sets direction = `self.mdown`

```
def chase(self,direction):
    if self.sqrx > char.sqrx :
        self.sqrx -= 1
        self.x = self.sqrx * size_sprite 
        self.direction = self.mleft
```